# How to connect multiple Tap streams for multiple plots in Holoviews?

Tags: python, holoviews

I would like to create an interactive visualization of 3D data as 3 slice views. For that I've created the plot.

Now I would like to add interaction such that I can select (x,y,z) in each plot. Depending on the selected plots only 2 or the 3 values should be updated, of course.

I coded the following.

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

hv.extension("bokeh")

size = 100
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(size), np.arange(size), np.arange(size))

data = ((abs(x - 50) + abs(y - 50) + abs(z - 50)) < 20).astype(np.int8)


def plot(data):
    def dynamic_plot(x0, y0, z0, y1, z1, x2, z2, x3, y3):
        return (
            hv.Image(hv_data_set[x0, :, :], kdims=["y", "z"])
            + hv.Image(hv_data_set[:, y0, :], kdims=["x", "z"])
            + hv.Image(hv_data_set[:, :, z0], kdims=["x", "y"])
            + hv.ItemTable(
                [("x2", x2), ("x3", x3), ("y1", y1), ("y3", y3), ("z1", z1), ("z2", z2)]
            )
        ).cols(2)

    hv_data_set = hv.Dataset(data)

    streams = [
        hv.streams.Tap(rename={"x": "y1", "y": "z1"}),
        hv.streams.Tap(rename={"x": "x2", "y": "z2"}),
        hv.streams.Tap(rename={"x": "x3", "y": "y3"}),
    ]

    return (
        hv.DynamicMap(dynamic_plot, kdims=["x0", "y0", "z0"], streams=streams)
        .redim.range(
            x0=(0, data.shape[0]), y0=(0, data.shape[1]), z0=(0, data.shape[2])
        )
        .redim.default(x0=50, y0=50, z0=50)
    )


xr_data = xr.DataArray(
    data,
    coords={
        "x": range(data.shape[0]),
        "y": range(data.shape[1]),
        "z": range(data.shape[2]),
    },
    name="val",
)

plot(xr_data)
```

[image: Holoviews Slicer]

However, a click in a plot seems to activate all variables. Moreover, the x0,y0,z0 values (in the title and the sliders) are not updated.

How can I connect the mouse clicks such that it would update the appropriate values (including the title and right sliders). For example when clicking in the top right plot naturally only x0 and z0 should be updated.

(also do you see boilerplate code I could remove or use holoviews in a neater way?)